# Почему find_library() не ищет путь внутри CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: cmake

С полным путём ищет, а так (см. ниже) нет.

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH C:/Users/me/Desktop/)

find_library(av_codec
    NAMES
        avcodec
    HINTS
         ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib
    REQUIRED
)

message(${av_codec})
```

Как это объяснить? Вот [здесь](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) чёрным по белому написано:

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying a search path for
> the find_library() command

К тому же `REQUIRED` не ломает конфигурацию, при том, что `av_codec-NOTFOUND` (через `message()`). Это баги *CMake*, или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, для этого есть `PATH_SUFFIXES`, а `PATHS`/`HINTS` так не работает (пути не конкатенируются):

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH C:/Users/march/Desktop/)

find_library(av_codec
    NAMES
        avcodec
    PATH_SUFFIXES
        ffmpeg-4.3-win64-dev/lib/
    REQUIRED
)

message(${av_codec})
```